# \includepdf command disappear the pdf's transparency information?

Tags: graphics, pdf, pdfpages, transparency, ghostscript

I have a pdf which has some transparent graphics and words.
Like this:(of course it had more words )

[image: origin pdf]

then I use \includepdf command to insert this to a latex project .

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
    \includepdf[pages={-}]{未转曲文件---删除多余图片1}
\end{document}
```

then I curve this pdf through ghostscript tool

> gs  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK    -sColorConversionStrategyForImages=CMYK  -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK   -o  ./dest.pdf  -f  ./source.pdf

then it becomes like this:
[image: after \includepdf and curve]

After using pdf-praser to analize it

```
/usr/bin/python pdf-parser.py  -o 67 document.pdf
```

, I found

> \includepdf

command in latex makes pdf structure has changed a lot.

origin pdf has a /group which contains transparency information if I am not wrong :
[image]

but then it just disappear.

I wonder the reason and it troubles me a week .

Hope for answer.

https://github.com/David553/latex.git

It's my test pdf files.

- origin-file.pdf is origin pdf file;
- delete-redundant-thing is the file which I delete redundant words and images to convenient test ;
- after-includepdf.pdf is the file which I use \includepdf{} command in latex;
- after-gs.pdf is the file which I use ghostscript line command to curve ;

Comment: Could you add a MWE that replicates your problem? and Welcome to TeX.Se

Comment: sorry , I don't understand the meaning of  MWE.

Comment: We need something that we can use for tests.

Comment: I don't find a way to upload pdf ~ , maybe  I can give you a github url     https://github.com/David553/latex.git

Comment: I cannot see it with an up-to-date TeXLive 2019 and ghostscript 9.26

Comment: Why do you use ghostscript to produce pdfs and not one of the engines that can pdf directly (like pdftex and luatex)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Why do you use ghostscript to produce pdfs and not one of the engines that can pdf directly (like pdftex and luatex)?
Because I want to curve the pdf , which means others can not easily copy my pdf words , and sooner I'll send the book to printer shop.

Comment: The above gs command converts the Color pdf into grayscale.

Comment: Generally archive quality pdf disallows transparency (and having worked through so many opacity/translucency/transparency  issues I agree they should not generally be allowed for general consumption it creates downstream havoc the key is to ensure the version is higher that latex recommends. If you do want to publish DONT use transparency it will likely be invalidated by the publisher to ensure the files are universally readable

Comment: Sorry, I have modify the gs command to what I use . I use CMYK strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Use an PDF newly produced by adobe illustrator2019 and textLive 2019 solve this transparency problem.

thanks to

```
I cannot see it with an up-to-date TeXLive 2019 and ghostscript 9.26 – Red-Cloud May 9 at 12:26
```

AI software gives me a hint that pantone color with transparency and transform to print color such as CMYK may cause unexpected problem!

[image: The AI software hint]